# Как можно оптимизировать этот код на рекурсию?

Tags: python, рекурсия, python-3.6

Я написал функцию, которая выводит все числа от **n** до **x** за счёт рекурсии, но чую, что-то я сделала не так. Помогите мне пожалуйста, дайте парочку советов по оптимизации кода!

```
# вывод: 1 2 3 4 5 
def rec(x, n=0, string=""):
    if n == x:
        print(string)
        return None
    n += 1
    string += str(n) + " "
    rec(x, n, string)

rec(5)
```

Comment: Ответ мне примите, если помог.

Answer (score 0):

Питон под час лучше знания алгоритмов:

```
print(*range(int(input())+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно оставить рекурсию, то так можно

```
def rec(x, n=0, string=""):
    if x == n:
        print(string)
        return
    n += 1
    string = ''.join([string, str(n), ' '])
    rec(x, n, string)
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас практически всё правильно было, только строка не в том месте дополнялась (плюс сделал небольшие изменения, чтобы код чуть короче был):

```
# вывод: 1 2 3 4 5 
def rec(x, n=0, string=""):
    string += str(n) + " " # <- переставил сюда
    if n == x:
        print(string)
        return # None не нужен, его всё-равно никто потом не смотрит
    rec(x, n + 1, string) # n можно при вызове функции увеличивать

rec(5)
```

Результат:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```